# In a private blockchain (for an business), how is sensitive information kept secure when each node becomes a potential leak of information?

Tags: blockchain

In a permissioned blockchain, every node has a full copy of the ledger. If a node is hacked, then the whole company's sensitive data will be compromised. How is this addressed in enterprise blockchain architecture?

Comment: My understanding is that each block has a hash of the previous block. As hashes are destructive, it isn't possible to reconstruct the ledger by examining the hashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your private data into a separate side database while your blockchain ledger/database will contain the hash value of your private data.

Different blockchain platform have different architecture for resolving this situation. So far Hyperledger Fabric is considered as the most popular blockchain platform for private and permissioned  blockchain framework.

You can check the following link for better understanding:
https://medium.com/coinmonks/private-public-data-at-hyperledger-fabric-v1-4-ff9f303f4bc1